# Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate

Tags: ios, xcode

I have two iOS developer and provisioning account. One is for my personal and the rest is for my office. My personal one is ok before adding my office account. After adding office account into my mac, both certificates has got following[image] two errors.

[image]

Comment: delete the distribution certificate and recreate it.

Comment: so, how about update version for my existing app?

Comment: I don't think your existing app would get affected if its already in the App store! you need to delete the cert that has caused the issue.